# This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions

Tags: payment-processor, paypal

I am getting this error message in Paypal (Live transaction) My sandbox (testing) working alright

> This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.

Any help is much appreciated

Also we do have previous question similar to this issue but was 2 years old.
[PayPal Website Payments Pro: This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18410/paypal-website-payments-pro-this-transaction-cannot-be-processed-the-merchant)

Thanks in Advance `

Comment: Which of the three PayPal payment processors are you using? If using Pro or Express, you need to enable that feature in your PayPal account ($30/month, + $10/month for recurring transactions). PayPal Standard has no monthly charge.

Comment: @Bobs thanks - I found out that only for upgraded Account Paypal Pro works - I did manage to change to Paypal standard and it works - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@Bobs thanks - I found out that only for upgraded Account Paypal Pro works - I did manage to change to Paypal standard and it works - Thanks